# Unable to instantiate MatchXpath

Tags: java, checkstyle

I got Checkstyle setup with [the Gradle plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/checkstyle_plugin.html). I'm trying to setup a rule enforcing the usage of `var`s in all local variables.

```
<module name="Checker">
        <module name="MatchXpath">
            <property name="query"
                      value="//VARIABLE_DEF[./ASSIGN/EXPR and not(./TYPE/IDENT[@text='var'])]"/>
            <message key="matchxpath.match"
                     value="Local variables should use 'var' keyword"/>
        </module>
    </module>
</module>
```

However, the configuration above throws the following error. All the other rules work fine so it has something to do with the "`MatchXpath`" module.

```
Caused by: com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.CheckstyleException: cannot initialize module TreeWalker - cannot initialize module MatchXpath - Unable to instantiate 'MatchXpath' class, it is also not possible to instantiate it as .MatchXpath, MatchXpathCheck, .MatchXpathCheck. Please recheck that class name is specified as canonical name or read how to configure short name usage https://checkstyle.org/config.html#Packages. Please also recheck that provided ClassLoader to Checker is configured correctly.
        at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.Checker.setupChild(Checker.java:482)
        at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.AutomaticBean.configure(AutomaticBean.java:201)
        at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.ant.CheckstyleAntTask.createRootModule(CheckstyleAntTask.java:421)
        ... 149 more
Caused by: com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.CheckstyleException: cannot initialize module MatchXpath - Unable to instantiate 'MatchXpath' class, it is also not possible to instantiate it as .MatchXpath, MatchXpathCheck, .MatchXpathCheck. Please recheck that class name is specified as canonical name or read how to configure short name usage https://checkstyle.org/config.html#Packages. Please also recheck that provided ClassLoader to Checker is configured correctly.
        at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.TreeWalker.setupChild(TreeWalker.java:125)
        at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.AutomaticBean.configure(AutomaticBean.java:201)
        at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.Checker.setupChild(Checker.java:477)
        ... 151 more
Caused by: com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.CheckstyleException: Unable to instantiate 'MatchXpath' class, it is also not possible to instantiate it as .MatchXpath, MatchXpathCheck, .MatchXpathCheck. Please recheck that class name is specified as canonical name or read how to configure short name usage https://checkstyle.org/config.html#Packages. Please also recheck that provided ClassLoader to Checker is configured correctly.
        at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.PackageObjectFactory.createModule(PackageObjectFactory.java:215)
        at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.TreeWalker.setupChild(TreeWalker.java:116)
        ... 153 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MatchXpath` was released with Checkstyle 8.39 . If you don't have atleast that version, then you are using too old a version.
https://checkstyle.org/config_coding.html#MatchXpath

You should double check what version of Checkstyle you are running and upgrade it if it is too low.

In addition, your config is missing `TreeWalker`, so it is not a fully valid config. The config should be:

```
<module name="Checker">
  <module name="TreeWalker">
        <module name="MatchXpath">
            <property name="query"
                      value="//VARIABLE_DEF[./ASSIGN/EXPR and not(./TYPE/IDENT[@text='var'])]"/>
            <message key="matchxpath.match"
                     value="Local variables should use 'var' keyword"/>
        </module>
  </module>
</module>
```

Comment: Bumping up the version solved the issue. Thanks!